# Collapse rows with associative ids - R

Tags: r

I use the following code to collapse rows:

```
new_df <- group_by(df, id) %>% summarize_each(funs(paste(., collapse = ',')))
```

But I'm having difficulty figuring out how to collapse rows when you have two associative ids in the same observation.  Rather than elaborate in words, below is my starting point and desired end point.

I need to go from this:

```
ID  ROW_ORDER   SERVICE
1234    1   Recordkeeping 
1234    1   Direct payment 
1234    1   Investment management 
1234    1   Other (specify)
1234    2   Trustee (bank)
1234    2   Trustee (discretionary)
1234    2   Investment management
5678    1   Investment management 
5678    1   Other (specify)
5678    1   Trustee (bank)
5678    2   Recordkeeping 
5678    2   Direct payment 
5678    2   Investment management
```

To this:

```
ID  ROW_ORDER   SERVICE
1234    1   Recordkeeping, Direct Investment,Investment Management,Other Specify,Trustee(bank)
1234    2   Trustee (bank),Trustee (discretionary),Investment 
5678    1   Investment management,Other(specify),Trustee (bank)
5678    2   Recordkeeping, Direct Investment,Investment Management
```

Comment: Group by `ID` and `ROW_ORDER`

Comment: Perhaps you need `group_by(df, ID, ROW_ORDER) %>% summarise(SERVICE = paste(SERVICE, collapse=","))`  As there is a single column, you don't need `summarise_each`

Comment: wow, that was a simple solution.  Thanks, @RichScriven and @akrun!

Comment: If you add it in the answers, I'll mark it as answered.  thanks again.